# Scraping with Python. Can't get wanted data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape website, but I encountered a problem. When I try to scrape data, it looks like the html differs from what I see on google inspect and from what I get from python. I get this with http://edition.cnn.com/election/results/states/arizona/house/01 I tried to scrape election results. I used this script to check HTML part of the webpage, and I noticed that they different. There is no classes that I need, like section-wrapper.

```
page =requests.get('http://edition.cnn.com/election/results/states/arizona/house/01')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
print(soup)
```

Anyone knows what is the problem ?

Comment: When using http libraries, you get what you see in the page's source code and not what you see when inspecting the page. You need to use 'something' that processes javascript (selenium, ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
http://data.cnn.com/ELECTION/2016/AZ/county/H_d1_county.json
```

This site use JavaScript fetch data, you can check the url above.

You can find this url in chrome dev-tools, there are many links, check it out
[image]

**Chrome >>F12>> network tab>>F5(refresh page)>>double click the .josn url>> open new tab**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have problem looking at these url.
I get     <H1>Unsupported Request</H1>
OPTIONS to http&#58;&#47;&#47;data&#46;cnn&#46;com&#47;ELECTION&#47;2016&#47;AZ&#47;county&#47;H&#95;d1&#95;county&#46;json not supported.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;8&#46;cb9c9bd5&#46;1485765909&#46;376f3f8b. When I try to look at data. Maybe you know why is it happening ? But you answer is good, thank you.

Comment: @Extria Chrome >>F12>> network tab>>F5(refresh page)>>double click the `.josn` url>> open new tab

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup       
page=requests.get('http://edition.cnn.com/election/results/states/arizona/house/01')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content)
#you can try all sorts of tags here I used class: "ad" and class:"ec-placeholder"
 g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"ec-placeholder"})
 h_data = soup.find_all("div"),{"class":"ad"}
 for item in g_data:print item
#print '\n'
#for item in h_data:print item
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answer. But that's the same thing I get, it doesn't show real data.